# Should I recommend deletion if someone else has already done so?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

While going through Review: Low Quality posts, I find a lot of ones that I would recommend to delete, but another user has already recommended it to be deleted (I assume they did seeing that most of the time there is one of the pre-set comments linked to a reason there). What should I do if it is already addressed? Do no reason to not add another comment, add another comment, or skip it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you feel something should be deleted in the low quality queue, go ahead and hit "Recommend Deletion". If it already has a comment, what I typically do is select no reason, but if you select the same reason as has already been specified, it won't leave a redundant comment.

When a post hits 6 recommend deletion votes (and possibly with no "Looks OK" votes, I'm not certain about that condition), it is deleted.

Comment: Ah, I just did not want to be placing comments for things already stated.

Comment: @ShadowZ. I usually upvote the comment if I am recommending deletion for the same reason.

Comment: I always thought the upvote was automatically added if you recommending deletion for the same reason